# Unable to flag question as moderator recommended

Tags: discussion

A user has apparently unsuccessfully been trying to compile nDPI over the last month, as evidenced by these [two](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30336498/4151918) [older](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30344558/4151918) and two [more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30938032/4151918) [recent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30938357/4151918) questions.

The last two questions were posted 15 minutes apart.  One asks how to compile a specific file within the project, and the other asks how to compile the entire project.

A mod had deleted [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31083744/4151918) of my identical answers, and suggested that I (tailor my answer or) flag the other question as duplicate.

Since the user is effectively asking the same question, and the steps are the same, whether they need to compile one file, or the whole project, I really can't tailor the answer.

I tried to flag the [single-file compilation question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30938032/4151918) as a duplicate, thinking it would be better to leave the more general (project compilation) question open.  However, the system won't let it be flagged, since "this question has an open bounty and cannot be closed."

I believe Martijn is right that one of the questions should be closed as a duplicate, but I can't even flag it :)

Can we close one of the questions?

Comment: If it has a bounty it can be closed by a mod (bounty may be returned). You need to flag other not flag duplicate.